# ASP.NET MVC Model Binding and Validation Order

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding, model-validation

I have a model (simplified) as follows:

```
public UserModel {
    ...
    public USState State {get; set; }
    public string StateString {get; set; }
    public Country Country {get; set; }
    ...
}
```

The validation rules I need are:

1. If `Country` is *USA* then `State` is required.
2. If `Country` is not *USA* then `StateString` is required.

I've created a custom validation attribute `RequiredIfAttribute`. This works fine so I'm not going to fill the question with it's implementation. It has three required members:

1. `CompareField` - This is the field it will use to check whether or not validation is required.
2. `CompareValue` - This is the value it will compare to to decide whether or not validation is required.
3. `CompareType` - This is how it will compare the value to decide whether or not validation is required.

So with this, I update my model as such:

```
public UserModel {
    ...
    [RequiredIf("Country", Country.USA, EqualityType.Equals)]    
    public USState State {get; set; }
    [RequiredIf("Country", Country.USA, EqualityType.NotEquals)] 
    public string StateString {get; set; }
    [Required]                                                   
    public Country Country {get; set; }
    ...
}
```

I should note here that my `RequiredIfAttribute` also has client side validation. This works perfectly.

Now on to the problem...

I'm posting the following values:

> State = *AL* 
>   StateString = *null* 
>   Country = *USA*

This meets my validation rules and should be valid. Here's the *but*. `ModelState` is telling me it is not valid. Apparently by StateString field is required. That's not what I specified. Why aren't my validation rules applied as expected?

***(If you know what's wrong at this point, then don't feel obliged to read the rest of the question)***

So here's what's happening. The `RequiredIfAttribute` is being triggered three times. But wait, I'm only using it twice. It is is being triggered like so:

1. Trigger on `StateString` (this comes back **invalid**)
2. Trigger on `State` (this comes back **valid**)
3. Trigger on `StateString` (this comes back **valid**)

This is pretty odd. It's validating `StateString` twice, first time it passes, second time it fails. The plot thickens...

I looked into this further to find that the first time it tries to validate `StateString`, `Country` **is not** set. The second time it tries to validate `StateString`, `Country` **is** set. Looking closer, it seem that the first attempt to validate `StateString` has occurred before my model has been fully bound. All properties (not listed in the sample model) that are below `StateString` (in code) are not bound. The second attempt to validate `StateString`, all properties are bound.

I have solved the problem, but I'm not confident in it because I simply do not trust it. To get my validation to work as expected, I rearranged the model as such (attributes removed for brevity):

```
public UserModel {
    ...
    public Country Country {get; set; }
    public USState State {get; set; }
    public string StateString {get; set; }
    ...
}
```

The `RequiredIfAttribute` still triggers three times as above but `ModelState` tells me that the posted data (as above) is now valid, like magic!

What I'm seeing is this (my assumptions):

```
1. Start binding (property by property, top to bottom in code (risky))
2. Arrive at `StateString` and decide to try and validate
3. Finish binding
4. Validate all properties
```

**I really have two questions:

 1. Why is this behaviour exhibited?

 2. How can I stop this behaviour?**

Comment: How did you manage to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a significant number of intricacies in the model binding process. Complex models will be fully re-validated.

I suggest that for a better understanding of the process you take a dive into the source code to appreciate what is really happening.

http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Http/ModelBinding/Binders/MutableObjectModelBinder.cs

There is a post-processing phase:

```
// post-processing, e.g. property setters and hooking up validation
ProcessDto(actionContext, bindingContext, dto);
bindingContext.ValidationNode.ValidateAllProperties = true; // complex models require full validation
```

There is a pre-processing phase:

```
// 'Required' validators need to run first so that we can provide useful error messages if
// the property setters throw, e.g. if we're setting entity keys to null. See comments in
// DefaultModelBinder.SetProperty() for more information.
```

There doesn't seem to be a whole lot of ways to influence this, aside from implementing your own model binder.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I can confirm that my custom attribute does in fact extend `RequiredAttribute`. So if this was not the case, do you think the behaviour I am seeing would not be exhibited?

Comment: I do think it's likely to solve the issue. You may be able to override the `IsRequired` property to return false, since the code seems to look for this when producing a list of required `ModelValidator`s